# table of content: bad result with addcontentsline

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters, page-numbering

i have a poor result when i try to add the introduction which is an unnumbered chapter to table of content through the command addcontentsline. LaTeX put the number of the page immediately next to the text "Introduction" resulting in something like "Introduction1" as i show in the pic. i provide the minimum compilable example which gives me that result. If I add other normal chapter they are represented normally in table of contents.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside,openright]{book} %oneside versione segreteria
\usepackage[english,italian]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=3cm,right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{bm}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}




\begin{document}

%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\frontmatter

\pagestyle{plain}        
\tableofcontents

%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\mainmatter

\pagestyle{plain} 

%Primo Capitolo
\addcontentsline{toc}{Chapter}{Introduzione}
\chapter*{Introduzione}

\end{document}
```

[image: result whit that code]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Use `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduzione}`, `chapter`, not `Chapter`. LaTeX **is** case-sensitive

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Glad you saw it. These are these kind of mysterious bugs, you track down like forever, because you simply read over it.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Oh jesus, was it so banal? Thanks a lot it worked. Oh and I read you're an astrophysicists. I hope you're glad to know you helped a guy to properly write his bachelor degree thesis in astronomy!

Comment: @Angeloferrari: I was an Astrophysicist (well, I am still one by heart) ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I didn't see your comment. Do you want [this](http://pastebin.com/JxTR4ekt)?

Comment: @cfr: You mean the missing chapter* command? Yes, perhaps but it's unclear and I provided no answer

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I just meant: my answer is the one you gave in a comment 30 minutes earlier. I was about to post it when I saw your comment. Since I'd written the code, I thought it might be useful. Though [the result](http://i.stack.imgur.com/nC6q7.png) would probably be helpful, as well.

Comment: @cfr - Well, go ahead -- I am writing on my Smartphone, this would take centuries to post an answer ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer OK. Well, in that case, I've added a CW answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [Christian Hupfer pointed out](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/312455/table-of-content-bad-result-with-addcontentsline?noredirect=1#comment760366_312455), the problem is that the sectional division `Chapter` is unknown. Probably you meant `chapter`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside,openright]{book} %oneside versione segreteria
\usepackage[english,italian]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=3cm,right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\pagestyle{plain}
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\pagestyle{plain}

%Primo Capitolo
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduzione}
\chapter*{Introduzione}

\end{document}
```

[image: correct contents line]